# Threshold for spark XGBoost Classification model

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, xgboost

How do I set an optimal threshold for an XGBoost classifier ? The default value used in the algorithm is 0.5. I wanted to know if there is any feature/in-built function I can use to change this.

Answer (score 1):

If using python: You are looking for `predict_proba()` python API instead of usual `predict()` API. With `predict_proba()` you get probability which then can be mapped to any class depending on threshold value.

Since you mentioned spark mllib so you might be using scala or java with xgboost4j. In such cases also options exist; for example `https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/scaladocs/xgboost4j/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/Booster.html#predict(data:ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.DMatrix,outPutMargin:Boolean,treeLimit:Int):Array[Array[Float]]` you are looking for `outPutMargin`

For deciding threshold you can use [ROC curve](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc) or evaluate you business outcome with xgboost outcome e.g. if all cases below score 0.8 are are loss making then you can set threshold to 0.8

Answer (score 0):

Using predict_proba(), like this:

```
# Assuming the data is split by x,y, and train, test accordingly

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
probabilities = model.predict_proba(x_test)

prediction_50 = (probabilities[:,1] >= 0.5).astype(bool) # 0.5 threshold - the default. equals to prediction 
prediction_60 = (probabilities[:,1] >= 0.6).astype(bool) # 0.6 threshold
prediction_70 = (probabilities[:,1] >= 0.7).astype(bool) # 0.7 threshold
```